# Can I use CGDataProviderCreateSequential() to read in the data of a CGImageRef sequentially?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, core-graphics, cgimage

Is it possible to use CGDataProviderCreateSequential() and CGDataProviderSequentialCallbacks to read the data in from a CGImageRef sequentially?

Currently I use CGDataProviderCopyData to get the data but that reads in all the data at once and eats up too much memory:

```
CFDataRef dataref = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imgRef));
```

Or is there any other way to sequentially read in the bytes of a cgimageref?

Answer (score -1):

You can find a very tidy example of direct byte access for CGImageRef in the answer to this:
[Getting the average RGB color of a CGImageRef in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623455/getting-the-average-rgb-color-of-a-cgimageref-in-ios)